# Why do I get a coredump when I try to catch an exception from boost::regex_match(text, e)?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

The following example is from the tutorial.
When I run it, it throws exception and then coredump.
I try to use catch() to catch the exception to avoid coredump like the following:

But it doesn't work. any suggestions?

Thanks

-Todd

---- coredump message BEGIN---

terminate called after throwing an instance of

'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'

what():  The repeat operator "*" cannot start a regular expression.  The error occured while parsing the regular expression: '>>>HERE>>>*'.

Abort (core dumped)

---- END---

--- program BEGIN ----

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
    void print_captures(const std::string& regx, const std::string& text)

    {

    boost::regex e(regx);

   boost::smatch what;

   std::cout << "Expression:  \"" << regx << "\"\n";

   std::cout << "Text:        \"" << text << "\"\n";

   try {

     //     boost::regex_match(text, what, e, boost::match_extra);

     boost::regex_match(text, e);

   }

   **catch(boost::regex_error& e) {

std::cout <<"!!!!\n"; 

   } 

   catch (...) {

     std::cout << "###\n"; 

   }** 



}


int main(int , char* [])

{
  print_captures("*", "AAA");

 }
```

---- END --

Answer (score 1):

It is the constructor of [`boost::regex()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/basic_regex.html#boost_regex.basic_regex.construct2) that is throwing the exception:

```
boost::regex e(regx);
```

Put the it inside the `try` block and it will be caught by the `boost::regex_error&` exception handler.